# No puedo acceder a variable global

Tags: javascript

Estoy tratando de usar el algoritmo heap para hallar las permutaciones posibles de un string. El problema es que cree una variable `perm` global para contar cada vez que tengo una permutación pero no puedo verla en un alert.

```
var perm=0;

function perm(str){

    var map={};
    var cnt=[];
    var letters=[];
    var length=str.length;
    var result=[];
    str=str.split("");  
    str=str.sort();
    alert(str);


    for(var i=0;i<str.length;i++){

        if(map[str[i]]) map[str[i]].cnt++;
        else map[str[i]] ={val:str[i],cnt:1};


    }

    for(var item in map){

        letters.push(map[item].val);
        cnt.push(map[item].cnt);

    }

    permAlone(letters,cnt,result,length,0);




}



function permAlone(str,cnt,result,length,level) {



    if(level===length){
        perm++;  
        return;

    } 


    for(var i=0;i<str.length;i++){
    //noprotect 


           if(cnt[i]===0) {continue;}


            result[level]=str[i];
            cnt[i]--;

            permAlone(str,cnt,result,length,level+1);
            cnt[i]++;


    }   



}



perm('aab');
alert(perm);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eso se debe a que nombras igual a tu función que a tu variable. Llámalas diferente, por ejemplo, ponle de nombre a tu función `permu`.

Tu código corregido:

```js
var perm=0;

function permu(str){

    var map={};
    var cnt=[];
    var letters=[];
    var length=str.length;
    var result=[];
    str=str.split("");  
    str=str.sort();
    alert(str);

    for(var i=0;i<str.length;i++){
        if(map[str[i]]) map[str[i]].cnt++;
        else map[str[i]] ={val:str[i],cnt:1};
    }

    for(var item in map){
        letters.push(map[item].val);
        cnt.push(map[item].cnt);
    }
    permAlone(letters,cnt,result,length,0);
}

function permAlone(str,cnt,result,length,level) {

    if(level===length){
        perm++;  
        return;
    } 
    
    for(var i=0;i<str.length;i++){
 
           if(cnt[i]===0) {continue;}

            result[level]=str[i];
            cnt[i]--;
            
            permAlone(str,cnt,result,length,level+1);
            cnt[i]++;
    }   
}

permu('aab');
alert(perm);
```

Comment: He intentado responder dos preguntas y te me haz adelantado, jajaja

Comment: @JoriusR Al menos no hago honor al nombre de mi usuario ^^

Comment: u.....ni cuenta me di :(  gracias!!

Answer (score 0):

¿No tiene que ver con que declaras la variable y a continuación una función con el mismo nombre?
Esto te va a dar un error.
Cambia la variable, por ejemplo, a xxx:

```
var xxx=0;

function perm(str){

    var map={};
    var cnt=[];
    var letters=[];
    var length=str.length;
    var result=[];
    str=str.split("");  
    str=str.sort();
    alert(str);


    for(var i=0;i<str.length;i++){

        if(map[str[i]]) map[str[i]].cnt++;
        else map[str[i]] ={val:str[i],cnt:1};


    }

    for(var item in map){

        letters.push(map[item].val);
        cnt.push(map[item].cnt);

    }

    permAlone(letters,cnt,result,length,0);




}



function permAlone(str,cnt,result,length,level) {



    if(level===length){
        xxx++;  
        return;

    } 


    for(var i=0;i<str.length;i++){
    //noprotect


           if(cnt[i]===0) {continue;}


            result[level]=str[i];
            cnt[i]--;

            permAlone(str,cnt,result,length,level+1);
            cnt[i]++;


    }   



}



perm('aab');
alert(xxx);
```